# How to notify that element form was changed?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I have some forms are generated by `FormGroup`.

```
class FormGroupCustom {
    form: FormGroup;
}

let forms: FormGroupCustom[] = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   this.forms.push({"formName": i, "form": new FormGroup()});
}
```

How can I notify `formName: 1` from array `this.forms` that any field was changed from `formName: 2`.

I have tried to apply Observer pattern, because I dont need to use reactive nested forms.

**My solution is:**

```
class Notify {

     notifyChange(formName: string, valueField: any) {
             // FIND form in array forms by formName
     }

}
```

Then apply `ng-change` on specific element if form like:

```
<input type="text" (ngChange)="change('formName1', 'value')"


change(formName: string, value: any) {
    let notify = new Notify();
    notify.notifyChange(formName, value);
}
```

So `notifyChange` can find form in array forms than do action over specific field in this form

Comment: Are you sure your provided code example is functioning? I don't think you can push `"formName": i, "form": new FormGroup()` into an array. Are you missing an object literal `{}`?

Comment: Sorry it is object, I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  this.forms.push({formName: i, form: new FormGroup({}) });
  let s = this.forms[i].form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    // do something when form control changes
  })

  this.subs.push(s)
}
```

There is a valueChanges() observable that you can subscribe to, to do something when the value of a form changes, is that what you are looking for?

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxfybv)

Comment: What about performance? I dont believe that it is good idea. Could I do this more OOP?I need to divide logic of notifier and forms. Forms I wrap by my class and store in array, because I need display forms in template